# If the constructor ends up with an exception, is the object created the same with a normal one?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

If the constructor ends up with an exception, is the object created exactly the same with a normal one?

```
class A {

    static A o;

    A() throws Exception {
        o=this;
        throw new Exception();
    }

    void f() { System.out.println("f(): entry."); };

    static public void main(String[]args ) {
        try {
         A o =new A();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }

        A.o.f(); // Is it safe to use this object?
       }
}
```

This compiles and runs, and the output of this program is:

```
Exception: java.lang.Exception
f(): entry.
```

Comment: is it Java? have you even tried compiling it?

Comment: @DonLi, user331225 is pointing out that you're missing a `}` so your code sample will not compile.

Comment: (A very interesting question, by the way.  I can't see why someone is asking it to be closed.)

Comment: @DonLi.. very interesting question.. my thoughts are that the object should be ready for gc after the exception.. but as it is referenced by a class member before it is gc-eligible.. it will not be gc'd.. so technically that object will be usable till the jvm has loaded the class `A`.. good job!

Comment: @user331225 -- There's nothing really that would make that object more or less eligible to be garbage-collected than any other object.  If it's reachable it will persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you catch the exception, the constructed object is never passed back to the caller, and the caller's result variable is not set.  However, the static variable would, in theory, be set, and I can't see any reason why it would not be accessible.

Note, however, that method verification will not allow you to store `this` until after the `super` constructor is called, so this is not a "back door" into otherwise protected objects.

Since it's your object, "safe" is up to you.

[A little more detail:  When the compiled version of your constructor is entered, the "raw" Java object is fully constructed -- no additional work is needed by the system to make it valid.  The `super` constructor has not been called yet, however, and it's either up to you to explicitly make a `super` call or have the compiler insert the `super` call by default (which it will do at the start of the method if you don't have an explicit call).  The "bytecode verifier" in the JVM has some very strict rules about what can happen in a constructor prior to calling the `super` constructor, and storing `this` to a static would be a definite no-no -- you'd get a VerifyError.]

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean "a VerifyError" ?

Comment: @DonLi -- java.lang.VerifyError, on loading the class.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  A.o.f(); // Is it safe to use this object?
> ```

It is a regular java object that will respond to method calls just as any other Java object.  This is not a source of undefined behavior as far as the Java language is concerned.

That doesn't mean it's safe to use.  Many classes' safety depends on their ability to maintain important invariants, and unexpected exceptions thrown during construction or critical operations often mean that those invariants do not hold so they are not safe to use.

Consider what happens if you subclass A

```
public class S extends A {
  boolean dirty;

  S() throws Exception {
    // Do work to maintain important security invariants.
    dirty = true;
  }

  void foo() {
    if (dirty) {
      System.out.println("clean");
      dirty = false;
    }
    System.out.println("foo");
  }

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    try {
      new S();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
    // Now A.o is an instance of S, but S's constructor
    // was never called.
    S s = (S) A.o;  // works.
    s.foo();  // Never prints clean before printing foo.
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely the point of this question relates to the fact that the constructor returns abnormally (so the assignment in the try statement never sees the result), yet a reference to the object can still be obtained.  You've not really addressed this with anything substantive (you're second paragraph skirts what I think is the OP's true issue).

Comment: @GregKopff, It is up to the asker to define "safe" but even though the asker did not supply a definition I answered for two common definitions -- it is not a source of undefined behavior, but is a common symptom when invariant violation has occurred.

Comment: where I think Hot Licks hit the nail on the head was the inclusion of the fact that you cannot use `this` unless the superconstructor has executed to completion.  With *that* information, a discussion of safety of the child class makes more sense.

Comment: @GregKopff, in my example, `this` is leaked by `super` which is why `S`'s constructor is never entered.  And remember that Java does not do the progressive vtable setting that C++ does, so even though `S`'s constructor is not entered, the resulting object is an `instanceof S`.